# C# - Webkit - Select a html dropdown item without selected attribute

Tags: c#

I need help. How can i select a dropdown item that does not have the selected attribute in C# using Webkit? The html is :

```
<select id="question" name="questionId">
                    <option value="">Text</option>

                    <option value="1">

                            Question 1

                    </option>

                    <option value="2">

                            Question 2

                    </option>

</select>
```